# Delete rows if two criteria match

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets with data and I would like to have delete rows in sheet1 if two criterias are matching. I've made a mindmap of an idea, so it is easier to understand.

[image]

I have done a very first part of the code what deletes rows when one criteria is matching, but it also deletes blank rows that I wanted to keep.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim iListCount As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim iCtr As Long

iListCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

For Each x In Sheets("Laoseis").Range("B4:B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
  For iCtr = iListCount To 16 Step -1
    If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).Value Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next iCtr
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can an AND condition in your if (or multiple), something like `If x.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).Value & x.Value <> "" Then Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).EntireRow.Delete` (if you have only one line in your if to do, you can put it on the same line and end if is not required). I didn't fully read your code and logic, but to apply 2 conditions to what you have there, that's how I would aproach it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim iListCount As Long, iCtr As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook

        iListCount = .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell In .Sheets("Laoseis").Range("B4:B" & iListCount)

          For iCtr = iListCount To 16 Step -1

            If cell.Value = .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).Value And cell.Value <> "" Then
                .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCtr, 14).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

          Next iCtr

        Next cell

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```